# Loopback adapter cannot connect to the domain network

Tags: load-balancing, network-share, local-area-network, loopback

I am working on a project creating Microsoft Print Server Farms with High-availability. It works perfectly with the Loopback adapters in the servers and a network load-balancer. The Loopback adapters are configured with the same setting and the ip address for network load-balancing. However, after I disable and re-enable the Loopback adapters, 1 server cannot connect to the domain anymore and its NetBIOS table becomes empty. Does anyone know what's happening?

Below are the registries added:

DisableLoopbackCheck: 1

DisableStrictNameChecking: 1

OptionalNames: The name of virtual network interface in NLB

srvcomment: Server 1 of PrintService cluster

The setting of Loopback Adapter: Disabled "Register this connection's address to DNS" and you might see the remaining setting in the image description

[image]

Comment: I have found a solution. I disable the Loopback adapter first. Then, I re-enable the NetBIOS of Ethernet Adapter to get the NetBIOS name because this action does not work with Loopback adapters. Finally, I re-enable the Loopback adapter and disable the NetBIOS of Ethernet Adapter. The NetBIOS Names in Ethernet adapter are shifted to Loopback adapter. I don't know why it works.